# How to calculate average time for several runs in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a SQLite database with the time for different runs. The time is stored as text and has the following format: MM:SS.fff for example 04:20.458 for 4 minutes, 20 seconds and 458 milliseconds.

What I would like to achieve is to get the average time of all runs. What I have done so far is to run a SQL query and write the result into a pandas dataframe. Data looks like this:

```
          time
0    04:58.244
1    05:01.509
2    04:56.664
3    04:48.271
4    04:48.853
..         ...
```

As a next step I have converted the text values into a datetime format like this:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%M:%S.%f')
```

Output is now as following:

```
                       time
0   1900-01-01 00:04:58.244
1   1900-01-01 00:05:01.509
2   1900-01-01 00:04:56.664
3   1900-01-01 00:04:48.271
4   1900-01-01 00:04:48.853
..                      ...
```

And here I am stuck. Using mean() returns nothing. All I found are instructions on how to calculate the difference between times, but as written before, I am interested in an overall average of the times. Unfortunately, I found nothing that helped me to make it work.

Some tips or help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Use `pd.to_timedelta`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_timedelta`. However, it expects the format to be `HH:MM:SS.fff`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df['time'])
avg_time = df['time'].mean().total_seconds()
```